# Unable to remove package from Ubuntu software

Tags: server, mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm very new to Linux. so that i try Ubuntu.
I install MySQL server and works then i install MySQL it shows me some error. And I get rid by reference documentation
https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-mysql-on-ubuntu-20-04

But the problem is when I try to access  MySQL server in terminal, it shows

> access denied root because of password: NO

I got frustrated and deleted all of them, but in Ubuntu software I can't remove that dev package. It shows

> unable to find package(s)

Comment: what do you mean "deleted all of them ?" what did you do ?

Comment: You have to supply the root password that you assigned during the install to be able to access the database from mysql-workbench.

Answer (score 0):

The ONLY way to remove packages is to to use `sudo apt remove ..` or using dpkg.. If you didn't do that, reinstall the packages with `sudo apt install ...`. then you could remove them as described above.

But your main problem is, that you setup an insecure password. Any decent database should not happy with that.

Comment: The whole point of this matter is that **sudo apt install etc** and **sudo apt remove etc**  do **NOT** work when parts of packages are missing or deleted. Until old bits of installations are fully removed apt won't make a fresh installation.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like the package may be sort of half-removed, i.e. executable parts of the package in /usr/lib and the data folder in your home directory may be deleted but there may remain an entry for the package in the status file.

Sign in as root and open /var/lib/dpkg/status file via:

```
sudo gedit /var/lib/dpkg/status
```

Now use CTRL-F to search for the package name inside this file.

When you find it, select all details relating to that package, i.e. between the blank line above it and the blank line below it, and delete that from the file and save the status file.

This stops the package manager looking for updates for the removed package.

Now reboot.